# ZF2 - Custom View Helper not load with getServiceLocator

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create a View Helper to "inject" a database value to my layout.phtml. It's result with a simple string but when I call a table gateway it's not result and not load the other html.

//Conversa/src/View/Helper/Conversas.php

```
namespace Conversa\View\Helper;

use Conversa\Model\ConversaTable;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Conversas extends AbstractHelper
{

    protected $sm;
    protected $mensagemTable;
    protected $conversaTable;

    public function __construct($sm)
    {
        $this->sm = $sm;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['id_utilizador'];

        //$conversas = $this->getConversaTable()->conversasUtilizadorAll($id);
        //$conversaTable = new ConversaTable();

        $c = $this->getConversaTable()->fetchAll(); // <-When I call this, it doesn't work anymore

        $output = sprintf("I have seen 'The Jerk' %d time(s).", $this->conversaTable);
        return htmlspecialchars($output, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }

    public function getConversaTable()
    {
        if (!$this->conversaTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->conversaTable = $sm->get('Conversa\Model\ConversaTable');
        }
        return $this->conversaTable;
    }

    public function getMensagemTable()
    {
        if (!$this->mensagemTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->mensagemTable = $sm->get('Mensagem\Model\MensagemTable');
        }
        return $this->mensagemTable;
    }
}
```

Module.php

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'conversas' => function ($sm) {
                $helper = new View\Helper\Conversas;
                return $helper;
            }

        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to go on here since you didn't include any info about *what* happens (error message?), however, your view helper factory doesn't look right. Your view helper constructor method has a required argument for the Service Manager, so you need to pass that:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'conversas' => function ($sm) {
                $helper = new View\Helper\Conversas($sm);
                return $helper;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Also, since your view helper requires `conversaTable`, it might be better to pass that to the view helper instead of the service manager (as the service locator functionality you're relying on was removed in ZF3).